# Why didn't I receive the "EV_KEY" event on some rooted Android devices when request getevent?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, touch, root

I work with rooted android devices for a study at my university.
Therefore I need to record touch events on the device independent of the application.

I have implemented this with an output stream where I send:

```
getevent -lt /dev/input/event3 \n
```

(the event corresponds to the touchscreen).

This works pretty nice for my device Samsung S4 Android 4.3.
Unfortunately I tested it on a few other devices with different Android versions (higher than 4.3) and I miss one important event `EV_KEY` which is for button up resp. down that means the finger start touching the screen and release it.

This is the response I get on my Samsung S4 for a button touch:

```
[   12972.567843] EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            DOWN                
[   12972.567873] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    000002ae            
[   12972.567873] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000052f            
[   12972.567904] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   00000012            
[   12972.567934] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR   00000009            
[   12972.567934] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_WIDTH_MAJOR   00000002            
[   12972.567965] EV_ABS       003c                 00000000            
[   12972.568087] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
[   12972.584658] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MAJOR   0000001b            
[   12972.584688] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TOUCH_MINOR   0000001b            
[   12972.584688] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_WIDTH_MAJOR   00000008            
[   12972.584688] EV_ABS       003c                 fffffffe            
[   12972.584719] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
[   12972.606325] EV_ABS       003c                 fffffff9            
[   12972.606356] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
[   12972.627444] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   ffffffff            
[   12972.627505] EV_KEY       BTN_TOUCH            UP
```

This is the response I get on other devices:

```
[    3078.948355] EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000            
[    3079.162730] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_TRACKING_ID   000003a3            
[    3079.162821] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_X    00000404            
[    3079.162882] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_POSITION_Y    0000043d            
[    3079.162913] EV_ABS       ABS_MT_PRESSURE      0000003b
```

Does anyone know why I don't get the `EV_KEY` event?
Is it in case of the Android version?
How can I fix this, to get this event?
Is there an other way to receive touch events app independent?

Answer (score 1):

In android getevent api is used to list events generated by device registered to input subsystem `/dev/input/*`.

For sending events to user space , first device driver needs to register to input susbsystem with type of events it needs to send to user space. E.g. `EV_ABS,EV_REL, EV_KEY` etc. Then events are sent to /dev/input/eventN from driver using input subsystem on hardware event.

Hence its driver discretion to send whatever types of event with condition that it should set type of events to input layer to avoid event filteration.

As in your case EV_KEY event is not coming in next android version.It is happening due to the driver changes.

Because when any device gets upgraded to newer android version. From OEM perspective they tend to use latest drivers for touch,sensor etc. as generally OEM purchase touch ic,sensor ic from different vendors like synaptics,bosch and these vendors keep on updating their drivers/software layer to ensure  better performance.

This way when device gets new OS. Sometimes interface, event types changes.
For app development you can deal with this using your code in android version which can be read from system properties.

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.
Probably someone else know an other way to receive touch events app independent!
Thus I couldn't accept this answer as problem solved.